# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException por error 80080005 (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

Tags: excel, vb.net

Tengo una función vb.net que convierte un archivo csv a Excel y le da formato, aparte de crear copias de seguridad de los ficheros diaria, mensual y anualmente que funcionaba hasta hace 3 días, desde entonces me devuelve el error:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 80080005 Error en la ejecución de servidor (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).'" en la línea:"Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application()"

El código de mi función es:

```
Public Sub CsvAExcel()

    Dim anio As Short = Now.Year
    Dim inicio As Date = Date.Now
    Dim csvFilePath As String = "D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\Historico tension_" & anio & ".csv"
    Dim xlsxFilePath As String = "D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\Historico tension_" & anio & ".xlsx"

    ' LEEMOS EL csv Y CREAMOS EL LIBRO EXCEL

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application()
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Hoja1")
    xlWorkSheet.Name = "Año " & anio
    Dim row As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:E1")
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1

    Using sr As New StreamReader(csvFilePath)

        While Not sr.EndOfStream

            Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
            Dim values As String() = line.Split(","c)

            ' ESCRIBIMOS LOS VALORES DEL csv EN LA HOJA EXCEL

            For i As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1

                xlWorkSheet.Cells(rowIndex, i + 1) = values(i)

            Next

            rowIndex += 1

        End While

    End Using

    ' FORMATEAMOS LAS COLUMNAS

    xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:E1").Font.Color = DarkBlue
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:E1").Interior.Color = LightGray

    'FORMATEAMOS, GUARDAMOS Y CERRAMOS EL EXCEL 

    Dim M_Izq As Short = 53
    Dim M_Der As Short = 33
    Dim M_Sup As Short = 30
    Dim M_Inf As Short = 35

    'ORIENTACIÓN DE LA HOJA

    With xlWorkSheet.PageSetup

        .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait

        'CONFIGURACIÓN DE MÁRGENES

        .LeftMargin = M_Izq
        .RightMargin = M_Der
        .TopMargin = M_Sup
        .BottomMargin = M_Inf

    End With

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In row.Cells

        cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)

    Next

    ' OBTENEMOS EL RANGO DE LA PRIMERA FILA

    Dim headerRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("1:1")

    ' CONFIGURAMOS LA PROPIEDAD RowsToRepeatAtTop DEL OBJETO PageSetup DE CADA HOJA EXCEL

    For Each xlWorkSheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets

        xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"

    Next

    ' CONFIGURAMOS LA PROPIEDAD PrintTitleRows DEL OBJETO PageSetup DE CADA HOJA EXCEL

    For Each xlWorkSheet In xlWorkBook.Worksheets

        xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = headerRange.Address

    Next

    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4 'TAMAÑO DE PAPEL A4
    xlWorkSheet.Columns.Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    xlWorkSheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1), xlWorkSheet.Range("E1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)).Borders.LineStyle = 1
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A2", xlWorkSheet.Range("A2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)).Font.Color = Color.Blue
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A2", xlWorkSheet.Range("A2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)).NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    Dim usedRange As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

    'DAMOS FORMATO A LA COLUMNA SISTÓLICA

    Dim columnToSelect As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2", xlWorkSheet.Range("B2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    columnToSelect.Select()

    For Each celda As Excel.Range In columnToSelect.Cells

        If celda.Value <= 9 Or celda.Value >= 13.9 Then

            celda.Font.Color = Red
            celda.Font.Bold = True

        End If

    Next

    xlWorkSheet.Range("C2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Select()

    'DAMOS FORMATO A LA COLUMNA DIASTÓLICA

    Dim usedRange1 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
    Dim columnToSelect1 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("C2", xlWorkSheet.Range("C2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    columnToSelect1.Select()

    For Each celda1 As Excel.Range In columnToSelect1.Cells

        If celda1.Value <= 6 Or celda1.Value >= 9 Then

            celda1.Font.Color = Red
            celda1.Font.Bold = True

        End If

    Next

    xlWorkSheet.Range("D2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Select()

    'DAMOS FORMATO A LA COLUMNA PULSACIONES

    Dim usedRange2 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
    Dim columnToSelect2 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("D2", xlWorkSheet.Range("D2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    columnToSelect2.Select()

    For Each celda2 As Excel.Range In columnToSelect2.Cells

        If celda2.Value <= 50 Or celda2.Value >= 76 Then

            celda2.Font.Color = Red
            celda2.Font.Bold = True

        End If

    Next

    xlWorkSheet.Range("E2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Select()

    'DAMOS FORMATO A LA COLUMNA SATURACIÓN

    Dim usedRange3 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
    Dim columnToSelect3 As Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Range("E2", xlWorkSheet.Range("E2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    columnToSelect3.Select()

    For Each celda3 As Excel.Range In columnToSelect3.Cells

        If celda3.Value <= 94 Then

            celda3.Font.Color = Red
            celda3.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        If celda3.Value = 100 Then

            celda3.Font.Color = Green
            celda3.Font.Bold = True

        End If

    Next

    Dim lastRow As Integer = xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

    lastRow += 2

    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Select()
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Value = "MEDIAS: "
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Font.ColorIndex = 32
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Interior.Color = Color.Chartreuse
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=REDONDEAR(PROMEDIO(B2:B" & lastRow - 2 & ");1)"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range("B" & lastRow).Font.Bold = True
    xlWorkSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=REDONDEAR(PROMEDIO(C2:C" & lastRow - 2 & ");1)"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range("C" & lastRow).Font.Bold = True
    xlWorkSheet.Range("D" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=REDONDEAR(PROMEDIO(D2:D" & lastRow - 2 & ");0)"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("D" & lastRow).Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Range("D" & lastRow).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("D" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range("D" & lastRow).Font.Bold = True
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=REDONDEAR(PROMEDIO(E2:E" & lastRow - 2 & ");0)"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & lastRow).Font.Size = 12
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & lastRow).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & lastRow).HorizontalAlignment = 3
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & lastRow).Font.Bold = True

    xlWorkSheet.Range("A" & lastRow & ":E" & lastRow).Borders.LineStyle = 1 'BORDES DE LA HOJA
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E1").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown).Select()

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath)
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    ' LIMPIAMOS TODOS LOS PROCESOS DE EXCEL ABIERTOS DE LA MEMORIA 

    Dim P As Process

    Try

        For Each P In Process.GetProcesses

            If P.ProcessName.ToUpper Like "*EXCEL*" Then

                P.Kill()

            End If

        Next

    Catch

    End Try

    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()

    'CALCULAMOS EL TIEMPO QUE TARDA EN EJECUTAR LA ACTUALIZACIÓN

    Dim fin As Date = Date.Now
    Dim totalSeg As String = "00"
    Dim total As New TimeSpan(fin.Ticks - inicio.Ticks)

    If total.Hours = 0 And total.Minutes = 0 Then

        totalSeg = total.Seconds.ToString("00")

    End If

    MessageBox.Show("¡csv CONVERTIDO Y FORMATEADO A xlsx EN " & totalSeg & " SEGUNDOS!", " ACTUALIZACIÓN EXCEL. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    'BORRAMOS EL csv DESPUÉS DE CREAR EL xlsx

    File.Delete(csvFilePath)

    'HACEMOS BACKUP DE LA BD

    Shell("D:\BBDD\PostgreSQL\tension_bkp.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)

    'GUARDAMOS EL ARCHIVO Y BORRAMOS EL BACKUP ANTERIOR

    Dim Directory As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\Backup_BD\")
    Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("*.backup").Where(Function(f) f.CreationTime < Date.Today)
    Dim fechaHoy As Date = Today
    Dim mesActual As String = Now.ToString("MM")
    Dim anioActual As String = Now.Year
    Dim fechaAyer As String = Format(Now.AddDays(-1), "dd-MM-yyyy")
    Dim mesPasado As String = Format(Now.AddMonths(-1), "dd-MM-yyyy")
    Dim numMesAnterior As Short = Date.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month

    For Each file In files

        file.Delete()

    Next

    MessageBox.Show("BACKUP REALIZADO CON ÉXITO.", " COPIA DIARIA DE LA BD. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    Dim permitirCopiaDeSeguridadEnCualquierMomento As Boolean = False

    ' COMPROBAMOS SI EL ARCHIVO DE COPIA DE SEGURIDAD MENSUAL EXISTE

    fileExists = File.Exists("F:\Backup_tension\Backup_BD\tension_01-" & mesActual & "-" & anioActual & ".backup")

    ' HACEMOS LA COPIA DE SEGURIDAD SI ES PRIMERO DE MES O SI NO EXISTE LA COPIA

    If fechaHoy.Day = 1 Or permitirCopiaDeSeguridadEnCualquierMomento = True Or fileExists = False Then

        'COPIA DE SEGURIDAD. HACEMOS BACKUP DE LA BD

        Thread.Sleep(1000) 'HACEMOS UNA PAUSA PARA QUE SUBA EL BACKUP 

        Shell("D:\BBDD\PostgreSQL\Backup_mensual.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)

        'BORRAMOS EL csv DESPUÉS DE CREAR EL xlsx

        File.Delete(csvFilePath)

        'GUARDAMOS EL ARCHIVO Y BORRAMOS EL BACKUP ANTERIOR

        Dim Directorio As New DirectoryInfo("D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\Backup_BD\")
        Dim ficheros = Directorio.GetFiles("*.backup").Where(Function(f) f.CreationTime < Date.Today)

        Dim Hoy As Date = Now
        Dim Actual As String = Now.ToString("MM")
        Dim actualAnio As String = Now.Year
        Dim ayer As String = Format(Now.AddDays(-1), "dd-MM-yyyy")
        Dim pasadoMes As String = Format(Now.AddMonths(-1), "dd-MM-yyyy")
        Dim numeroMesAnterior As Short = Date.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month

        For Each fichero As FileInfo In files

            fichero.Delete()

        Next

        MessageBox.Show("BACKUP HECHO.", " COPIA MENSUAL DE LA BD. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Dim today As Date = Date.Today
        Dim firstDayOfMonth As Date = New Date(today.Year, today.Month, 1)
        Dim fileName As String = String.Format("tension_{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.backup", firstDayOfMonth)

        'COMPROBAMOS SI EL DÍA DEL MES ES 1 O SI NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO GUARDADO CON ESA FECHA, EXCEPTO EL 1 DE ENERO

        If (today.Day = 1 AndAlso today.Month <> 1) Then

            Dim backupPath As String = "F:\Backup_tension\Backup_BD\" & fileName

            If Not File.Exists(backupPath) Then

                'COPIAMOS LA CARPETA EN EL DISCO DE BACKUPS

                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension", "F:\Backup_tension", True)

                'CREAMOS UN ARCHIVO VACÍO CON EL NOMBRE DEL DÍA 1 DEL MES PARA CONFIRMAR QUE SE HA REALIZADO LA COPIA

                File.Create("F:\Backup_tension\Backup_BD\" & fileName).Dispose()

                MessageBox.Show("COPIAS DE SEGURIDAD COMPLETADAS CON ÉXITO.", " COPIAS DE SEGURIDAD. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            Else

                MessageBox.Show("EL ARCHIVO YA EXISTE.", "INFO.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            End If

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("HOY NO ES PRIMERO DE MES O ES ENERO.", "INFO.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End If

        'COMPRIMIMOS LOS ARCHIVOS DEL MES ACTUAL EN UN ZIP Y GUARDAMOS

        Dim ultimoMes As Date = today.AddMonths(-1)
        Dim ultimoMesName As String = ultimoMes.ToString("MMMM")
        Dim rutaOrigen As String = "D:\Documentos\Escaneados\Informe_medico_infarto_2019\Tension\"
        Dim rutaDestino As String = "F:\Backup_tension\Backup de_" & ultimoMesName & ".zip"
        Dim webRuta As String = "C:\xampp\htdocs\tension_web\"
        Dim webRutaDestino As String = "F:\Backup_tension\Backup web_" & ultimoMesName & ".zip"

        If File.Exists(rutaDestino) Then

            File.Delete(rutaDestino)

        End If

        CreateFromDirectory(rutaOrigen, rutaDestino)
        CreateFromDirectory(webRuta, webRutaDestino)

        MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVOS ZIP CREADOS CON ÉXITO.", " COMPRESIÓN DE ARCHIVOS. ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End If    

    conexion.Close()

End Sub
```

¿A qué se debe el error?

Comment: Me parece que se debe a que no encuentra la dll, lo que es seguro es que no tiene nada que ver con el código. Tienes que probar reinstalando el excel, registrando las dll y/o colocando las dll en la raíz del programa y todas esas cosas típicas que se hacían cuando se trabaja con dll COM. Si tu programa fuera solo el código que has mostrado yo te recomiendo buscar otra librería para trabajar con excel,

Comment: Hola, y ¿qué dll es?

Answer (score 0):

revisa esta linea
te dice como agregar la dll del office (en este caso excel necesria)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/403418)